# Warning in NumPy when setting array element to NaN using Spyder

Tags: python, numpy, nan, spyder

I am running Python 3.6.4 with Anaconda and Spyder.

When I am trying to set a value of a NumPy array to NaN I am getting the following RuntimeWarning.

```
a = numpy.array([5.0,2.0,1.0])

a[0] = numpy.nan
```

> C:\Users..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py:29:
> **RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce**   return
> umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
>
> C:\Users..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py:26:
> **RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce**   return
> umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)

Why is this happening?

Comment: See [this Github issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7063) - it looks like it is an issue with spyder.

Comment: not present in numpy '1.14.3'

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the NumPy version and everything works fine now.